# Numpy array of dtype object has vastly different values for sys.getsizeof() and nbytes

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, memory

I have a sample dataset of names. It is a csv file with 2 columns, each 200 lines long. Both columns contain random names. I have the following code to load the csv file into a pandas Dataframe, convert the dataframe into a numpy array, then convert the numpy array into a standard python list. The code is as follows:

```
x_df = pd.read_csv("names.csv")
x_np = x_df.to_numpy()
x_list = x_np.tolist()

print("Pandas dataframe:")
print('Using sys.getsizeof(): {}'.format(sys.getsizeof(x_df)))
print('Using pandas_df.memory_usage(): {}'.format(x_df.memory_usage(index=True, deep=True).sum()))

print('\nNumpy ndarray (dtype: {}):'.format(x_np.dtype))
print('Using sys.getsizeof(): {}'.format(sys.getsizeof(x_np)))
print('Using ndarray.nbytes: {}'.format(x_np.nbytes))
total_mem = 0
for row in x_np:
    for name in row:
        total_mem += sys.getsizeof(name)
print('Using sys.getsizeof() on each element in np array: {}'.format(total_mem))

print('\nStandard list:')
print('Using sys.getsizeof(): {}'.format(sys.getsizeof(x_list)))
total_mem = sum([sys.getsizeof(x) for sublist in x_list for x in sublist])
print('Using sys.getsizeof() on each element in list: {}'.format(total_mem))
```

The output of this code is as follows:

```
Pandas dataframe:
Using sys.getsizeof(): 25337
Using pandas_df.memory_usage(): 25305

Numpy ndarray (dtype: object):
Using sys.getsizeof(): 112
Using ndarray.nbytes: 3200
Using sys.getsizeof() on each element in np array: 21977

Standard list:
Using sys.getsizeof(): 1672
Using sys.getsizeof() on each element in list: 21977
```

I think I understand, for the standard python list, why `sys.getsizeof()` is such a small value compared to using `sys.getsizeof()` on each element of that list - using it on the list overall just shows the list object, which contains references to elements of the list.

Does this same logic apply to the numpy array? Why exactly is the value of `nbytes` on the array so small compared to the list? Does numpy have excellent memory management, or does the numpy array consist of references, not the actual objects? If the numpy array consists of references, not the actual objects, does this apply to all dtypes? Or just the object dtype?

Comment: getsize approximates the nbtyes of a numeric dtype pretty well,  But an object dtype is like a list containing references to objects elsewhere.

Comment: Also `getsizeof` of a numpy `view` tells you nothing useful.  In general I'd say forget `getsjzeof`

Answer (score 1):

A dataframe containing strings will be object dtype.

2*200*8 (8 bytes per pointer) is 3200, the array `nbytes`. The `112` is just the size of the array `object` (shape, strides etc), and not the databuffer.  It apparently is a `view` of the array that `x_df` is using to store it's references.

Pandas data storage is more complicated than `numpy`, but apparently if the dtype across columns is uniform, it does use a 2d `ndarray`.  I don't know how `getsizeof` and `memory_usage` (with those parameters) works, though the numbers suggest they are the same.

Your enumeration size suggests that the string elements are on the average 6-7 bytes long.  That seems small for unicode, but you haven't told us about those 'random names'.

The enumerated list apparently does the same same as the numpy enumeration.  I'm a little surprised that `1672` is so much small than `3200`, as though the list's pointer array holds 4 byte pointers rather than 8.